How to show all instances of a repeating event in the survey queue?
I am running a research project in RedCap which uses the survey queue to access all of the surveys and repeating events. The project involves some initial surveys that are completed once. After this, participants bring in drug samples which are inputted on a form by the researcher. Each sample results in a new instance of this form. Each sample has two associated surveys that I would like to be made available on the survey queue provided that the previous one has been completed. So, the two surveys are 'results' and 'postExperience'; I would like to have it set up so that once a sample is provided, the results survey for that sample becomes available, then once the results survey for that sample is completed, the postExperience survey for that sample becomes available. These two surveys and one form are currently setup as a repeating event. The survey queue works great for the first instance of the event however, when a 2nd instance of the event is initiated by creating a 2nd instance of the form, the other surveys do not become available. Is it possible to show all current instances of all current forms in the survey queue?
I tried using conditional logic that works with the current instance of the event in the survey queue however I just found that the survey queue and form display logic are not able to look at repeating events. Is there another way that this could be done? If I make the three instruments repeatable, is there any way to link them?

If you don't receive a satisfactory response on Stack Overflow, consider asking your local REDCap admins.  If they don't know, they can pose the question in the private forums (that is open only to other REDCap admins).
